# Basic JAVA app with setters and setters and increment an integer by 1

Tags: java, if-statement, selector, getter-setter

I'm just blanking on what to do next.

What I need to do:

- The class should have the variables name, breed, age, and color
- A constructor that sets all the variables
- Getters and Setters for all the variables
- A main method that creates an instance of the Dog and utilizes the
  constructor
- You can pick values you feel appropriate for the variables
- Increase the dog's age by 1
- Print all the values to the screen

Heres what I've done.

```
public class DOG {
    String DogName;
    String DogBreed;
    int DogAge;
    String DogColor;

    public DOG(String name, String color, String breed, int age) {
        this.DogName=name;
        this.DogColor=color;
        this.DogBreed= breed;
        this.DogAge=age;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DOG myDog = new DOG("Ares","Red","Rott",5);

        System.out.println(myDog.DogName+" " + myDog.DogColor+ " " + myDog.DogAge+ " " + myDog.DogBreed);

    }

    public void addOnetoAge() {
        if(DogAge >=6 DogAge++);
    }

    public String getDogName() {
        return DogName;
    }

    public void setDogName(String dogName) {
        DogName = dogName;
    }

    public String getDogBreed() {
        return DogBreed;
    }

    public void setDogBreed(String dogBreed) {
        DogBreed = dogBreed;
    }

    public int getDogAge() {
        return DogAge;
    }

    public void setDogAge(int dogAge) {
        DogAge = dogAge;
    }

    public String getDogColor() {
        return DogColor;
    }

    public void setDogColor(String dogColor) {
        DogColor = dogColor;
    }
    if(int i=1; i <= myDog.DogAge: i++) {
            System.out.println(myDog.DogAge);
        };

    }
}
```

I'm just getting back into java and have forgotten what goes where.
I would be grateful for a bit of direction

Comment: I think you mean `if(DogAge >=6)  DogAge++;`  But why does the dog need to 6 or older?

Comment: Also please try to following java naming conventions, variables begin with a lowercase char

Comment: Is this a homework? ;)

Comment: Also you need to call the method `myDog.addOnetoAge();`

Comment: This part needs to be within a method... `if(int i=1;`, also needs to be `for(int i`, not an if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, you have the right code, but your two `if` statements are not necessary, so you should remove both.

If you follow the assignment instructions

> - Increase the dog's age by 1
> - Print all the values to the screen

In your main method all you need to do is this

```
DOG d = new DOG("x", "y", "z", 2);
d.setAge(g.getAge() + 1); // Increase by one
System.out.println(...); // print the values of the getters
```

---

This would iterate a range of all the value between one and the dog age, not increase it

```
for(int i=1; i <= myDog.DogAge: i++) {
```

This only increases the ages for dogs 6 and older (which seems like a weird design)

```
if(DogAge >=6) DogAge++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your method for adding 1 to `DogAge`
instead of

```
public void addOnetoAge() {
    if(DogAge >=6 DogAge++);
}
```

use

```
public void addOnetoAge() {
    if(DogAge >=6) DogAge++;
}
```

also, don't forget to call your `addOnetoAge()` method when it's time to add 1 to `DogAge`

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your main method outside of the Dog class. This should work.

```
public class MainApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Dog goodBoy = new Dog("Milou", "Wire Fox Terrier", 6, "White");
       System.out.println(goodBoy.getDogName() + " " + goodBoy.getDogBreed() + " " + goodBoy.getDogAge() + goodBoy.getDogColor());
    }

}

class Dog
{
    private String dogName;
    private String dogBreed;
    private int dogAge;
    private String dogColor;

    public Dog(String dogName, String dogBreed, int dogAge, String dogColor)
    {
        this.dogName = dogName;
        this.dogBreed = dogBreed;
        this.dogAge = dogAge;
        this.dogColor = dogColor;
    }

    public String getDogName()
    {
        return dogName;
    }

    public void setDogName(String dogName)
    {
        this.dogName = dogName;
    }

    public String getDogBreed()
    {
        return dogBreed;
    }

    public void setDogBreed(String dogBreed)
    {
        this.dogBreed = dogBreed;
    }

    public int getDogAge()
    {
       return dogAge;
    }

    public void setDogAge(int dogAge)
    {
        this.dogAge = dogAge;
    }

    public String getDogColor()
    {
        return dogColor;
    }

    public void setDogColor(String dogColor)
    {
        this.dogColor = dogColor;
    }

    public void increaseAge()
    {
        this.dogAge++;
    }
}
```